# "invalid input syntax for type numeric" for entering "emptyness"

Tags: postgresql-9.2, coalesce, tsvector

I have a table with three columns using the NUMERIC type. However, two of them have nothing (ie. empty). Here it's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE profiles(
ID SMALLINT,
FID SMALLINT,
SURVEY VARCHAR(100),
PROFILE VARCHAR(100),
TYPE VARCHAR(100),
SOURCE VARCHAR(100),
NR_TRACES NUMERIC,
TRACE_SPACE_M NUMERIC,
LENGTH_M NUMERIC,
IMAGES TEXT,
COMMENTS TEXT
);

ALTER TABLE profiles ADD ts tsvector;

UPDATE profiles SET ts = to_tsvector('english', ID || ' ' || FID || ' ' || coalesce(SURVEY,'') || ' ' || coalesce(PROFILE,'') || ' ' || coalesce(TYPE,'') || ' ' || coalesce(SOURCE,'') || ' ' || coalesce(NR_TRACES,'') || ' ' || coalesce(TRACE_SPACE_M,'') || ' ' || coalesce(LENGTH_M,'') || ' ' || coalesce(IMAGES,'') || ' ' || coalesce(COMMENTS,''));
```

given that I'm updating my ts column with these two columns having nothing on them (NR_TRACES and TRACE_SPACE_M), the ts column is not populated. I found that it's empty because I updated afterwards both columns with:

```
UPDATE profiles SET nr_traces = 10131, trace_space_m = 12.5 WHERE PROFILE = '30';
```

and got:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
```

and

```
ERROR:  tsvector column "TS" does not exist
```

the column LENGTH_M, however, is completely populated, so I can say that "numeric" type doesn't allow coalesce in the way I'm using it. I also used the one below without success:

```
coalesce(my-numeric-empty-column,'')
coalesce(my-numeric-empty-column,'')::numeric
```

if I test the populated LENGTH_M column alone, I get the same pointing to the '' (empty) space:

```
psql:profiles.sql:146: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: ""
LINE 1: ... ' ' || TRACE_SPACE_M || ' ' || coalesce(LENGTH_M,'') || ' '...
                                                         ^
```

How can I circumvent this without populating in the first place these two empty columns?

I'd appreciate any hints on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are updating a `numeric` column, not a `tsvector` column. Also, to refer to an uppercase TS name in SQL, you need  double quotes, e.g. `"TS"`.

Comment: @MikeToews thanks Mike for the reply. Well in fact the ts column is being populated through an update statement. Please refer to my question for more info, I recently updated it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How `COALESCE` works is that it assumes the datatype from the first argument, then attempts to cast subsequent values to the first datatype. So the following shows the same error, since `''` cannot be cast as numeric:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL::numeric, '')
```

This is fixed by casting the first argument to `text`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL::numeric::text, '')
```

therefore your code could be fixed using `coalesce(length_m::text,'')`.

---

A similar approach is to collect the items in a text array, then [join the array to a string](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-array.html) with `' '`, and `''` for null elements.

```
UPDATE profiles
SET
  ts = to_tsvector(
    'english',
    array_to_string(
      ARRAY[id::text, fid::text, survey, profile, type, source,
            nr_traces::text, trace_space_m::text, length_m::text,
            images, comments],
    ' ', '')
  )
```

Comment: thanks Mike, even though this works, if I update these numeric columns with `UPDATE profiles SET nr_traces=10131, trace_space_m=12.5 WHERE PROFILE = '93-30';` this still appears `tsvector column "TS" does not exist`, so I cannot anymore update those columns with numbers?

Comment: just to point that I have a trigger for insert or updates like: `CREATE TRIGGER tsvectorupdate BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON profiles FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('TS', 'pg_catalog.english', ID, FID, SURVEY, PROFILE, TYPE, SOURCE, NR_TRACES, TRACE_SPACE_M, LENGTH_M, IMAGES, COMMENTS);`, here it's the problem I think

Comment: The column name needs to be `'ts'` since postgres is case-sensitive. Or, you could rename the column name to `"TS"`, but it is annoying in the long run to always double-quote things.

Comment: I changed to 'ts' but the problem still occurs. I run again the script but without the trigger, after that the update worked correctly, so the trigger is the problem, is there a way to adapt the trigger or something in it?

Comment: I tried recently NR_TRACES::numeric in the trigger but gave a syntax error at or near "::"