# [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation error while reading the result set next record

Tags: amazon-redshift

We are fetching the data from redshift db using JDBC way in java.
The query used for getting the data from tables is

```
select * from table_name limit 200;
```

Below are the errors occurred for different tables.
I am able to see the data in resultset .
But while getting next record of particular row it throwing the below errors. Could you please help us to understand the error and resolution for it.

Error 1:

```
`https://forums.aws.amazon.com/(500310) Invalid operation: Invalid input syntax for type numeric
Details:
error: Invalid input syntax for type numeric
code: 8001
context: value: ""
query: 88634410
location: cg_util.cpp:604
process: query19_773_88634410 https://forums.aws.amazon.com/
-----------------------------------------------;
at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGResultSet.hasMoreRows(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.updateCursorPosition(Unknown Source)`
```

Error 2: For other table

```
`https://forums.aws.amazon.com/(500310) Invalid operation: Divide by zero;
at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGResultSet.hasMoreRows(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.updateCursorPosition(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.next(Unknown Source)`
```

Error 3:

```
`java.sql.SQLException: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/(500310) Invalid operation: operator does not exist: text ||;
at com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.doMoveToNextClass(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.getParameterDescription(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.client.PGClient.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGQueryExecutor.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.dataengine.PGDataEngine.prepare(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.jdbc41.S41PreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.jdbc42.S42PreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.core.jdbc42.PGJDBC42PreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.redshift.core.jdbc42.PGJDBC42ObjectFactory.createPreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at com.amazon.jdbc.common.SConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)`
```

**error1 example** :JDBC mapped column details  for divide by zero error :Have 5 columns like=> x-VARCHAR, y-INTEGER , z-VARCHAR , l-VARCHAR,  r-DOUBLE

**error2 example** : JDBC mapped column details for valid input syntax for type numeric error => id-BIGINT,dt-TIMESTAMP,text-VARCHAR,money-NUMERIC

**error3 example** :we are not able to read the data from table also

```
Please share your thoughts on this
```

Comment: Until to see your actual record, its difficult to answer this. But I think it may be an invalid data type in one of your columns. Are all the columns are text or any integer or numeric? I would suggest you to check the data with all varchar. (read this to understand what Im trying to convey - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20182570/6885516) 
And the 2nd error, `https://forums.aws.amazon.com` is divided, its strange, because it should not happen via `select *` so try to run the select with all columns as varchar

Comment: Thanks Bhuvanesh for your response.Yes your guess might be true that is its due to invalid datatype.My doubt is i am doing just  select * from table and not doing any type conversion while fetching data.Also data is loaded to result  set .my question is Is it due to the JDBC datatype that mapped to the table doing the conversions?

Comment: I have updated the post with examples for better analysis of the issue

Comment: Does JDBC reading the data from table  will always be with varchar datatype and then it converts them later to the jdbc datatypes internally during which conversion happens?Not sure.Please help on this

Comment: Im not aware of the JDBC drivers internals, if you are using Redshift drivers, then it should work, (Or just for try, can you run this via psql cli tool?)